# How to change the datetimepicker value automatically while in progress

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to know is there any way to change the datetimpePicker value while in progress.

I am using this code to go the next day .

```
                DateTime stdate = new DateTime();
                stdate = dateTimePicker1.Value;

                while (stdate <= DateTime.Now)
                {
                    txtSelectedDate.Text = stdate.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
                    selectedDate = Convert.ToInt32(txtSelectedDate.Text);
                    stdate = stdate.AddDays(1);
                }
```

I want to change the datetimepicker value while in progress automatically because my my code works on date value if i select the date which is not present in the files it does not works , if i change the datetimepicker value which the file haves it works fine.

I want to change the datetimepicker value while in progress automatically.

There would be great appreciation if someone coulde help me.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I've understood your question but if you're looking to update the DateTimePicker after each increment, you just need to affect its Value property, something like this:

```
stdate = stdate.AddDays(1);
dateTimePicker1.Value = stdate;
```

Comment: thanks for the code its working fine but i cant vote you because i am not having much reputations to vote u sorry